# Getting distinct values with MIN - MAX values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Contracts Table) in an SQL database (SQLServer) as follows;

| Customer No | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/2020 |
| Customer1 | 01/01/2023 | 31/12/2023 |
| Customer 2 | 01/01/2024 | 01/01/2024 |
| Customer 2 | 01/01/2022 | 31/12/2022 |
| Customer 2 | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/2020 |
| Customer 3 | 01/01/2023 | 31/12/2023 |

I am trying to build a query that extracts the distinct customers and for each customer, returns also the oldest StartDate and the 'biggest' EndDate i.e. the result should be as follows;

| Customer No | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/2023 |
| Customer2 | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/2024 |
| Customer3 | 01/01/2023 | 31/12/2023 |

Query I attempted;

```
Select CustomerNo, StartDate, EndDate 
 FROM [Database].dbo.[Contracts] cont
 WHERE 
    StartDate=(
        SELECT MIN(StartDate)
        FROM [Database].dbo.[Contracts]
        WHERE CustVendNo = cont.CustVendNo
        GROUP BY CustVendNo)
AND 
EndDate=(
        SELECT MAX(EndDate)
        FROM [Database].dbo.[Contracts]
        WHERE CustVendNo = cont.CustVendNo
        GROUP BY CustVendNo)
```

The data being returned is incorrect and it is also ignoring certain customers.

Would anyone be able to assist, please?

Attempted the below query but results were not as expected

```
Select CustomerNo, StartDate, EndDate 
 FROM [Database].dbo.[Contracts] cont
 WHERE 
    StartDate=(
        SELECT MIN(StartDate)
        FROM [Database].dbo.[Contracts]
        WHERE CustVendNo = cont.CustVendNo
        GROUP BY CustVendNo)
AND 
EndDate=(
        SELECT MAX(EndDate)
        FROM [Database].dbo.[Contracts]
        WHERE CustVendNo = cont.CustVendNo
        GROUP BY CustVendNo)
```

Comment: what's wrong with `select customerno, min(startdate), max(enddate) from contracts group by customerno`

Comment: Take Customer1 for example; the `min(StartDate)` is 01/01/2020 and the `max(EndDate)` is 31/12/2023. And in the query you have written, for Customer1, it is asking for rows where `StartDate = '01/01/2020' and EndDate = '31/12/2023'`, of which there are none. I think you may be over-complicating things, and what @siggemannen wrote will probably get you want you want.

Comment: Presumably anyway; your sample data references `CustomerNo` but your query references `CustVendNo`. So I'm not quite sure what to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    CustomerNo, 
    MIN(StartDate) as StartDate, 
    MAX(EndDate) as EndDate
FROM 
    [Database].dbo.[Contracts]
GROUP BY 
    CustomerNo
```

you can use a `group by` query to get the minimum start date and maximum end date for each customer